# how can I delete all rows in a SQLite table which contains an element from an array

Tags: node.js, database, sqlite

I have a *SQLite* table (*masterTable*, below) in which one of the columns contains ledger numbers.

What I'm trying to do in *node.js*, is to delete rows from the *masterTable* **only if** the column (*thisColumn*, see below) matchs the elements from a given array (*ledger_num*, see below).
if the column contains any element from the array then the entire row must be deleted

Namely, I have the following array(const ledger_num), with an unknown number of elements in it

```
 const ledger_num = ['g12', 'g16', 'g45', 'gXX'];
```

```
sqlite table = 
thisColumn | name | date    | age | gender
g1         | bob  | 15/1/21 | 15  | male
g2         | john | 1/2/21  | 19  | male
g3         | Emma | 9/12/21 | 20  | female
.
.
g12        | rose | 1/1/21  | 21  | female
.
.
g16        | ben  | 8/8/21  | 31  | male
.
.
g45        | toby | 6/11/21 | 31  | male
.
gXX        | ---- | ---     | --  | ----
```

```
db.run(`DELETE FROM masterTable WHERE thisColumn = ?`,ledger_num ,(err)=>{
if(err) console.log(err)
})

//so this is what i was doing but this clearly does nothing
```

How do I do this in *node.js* so that the values from *thisColumn*, which match any of the elements in *ledger_num*, are deleted?

```
after deleting, the SQLite table should be  
thisColumn | name | date    | age | gender
g1         | bob  | 15/1/21 | 15  | male
g2         | john | 1/2/21  | 19  | male
g3         | Emma | 9/12/21 | 20  | female
.
.
gXX        | ---- | ---     | --  | ----
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by updating your sql command to include a `set` by using the [sql `IN` statement](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp), then [mapping over the array values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) replacing them with `?` and passing the array in as the next argument:

```js
db.run('DELETE FROM masterTable WHERE thisColumn IN ' +
   `(${ledger_num.map(function() { return '?' }).join(',')})`, 
   ledger_num,
   (err)=>{
      if(err) console.log(err)
   }
)
```

You create an array of ['?'] for every item in the `ledger_num` array then use the `join()` method to cast it to a string with `,` between.

Comment: so basically I am looping through all the items in the array and creating & joining it with the SQL ?

Comment: @docpinocchio No, this is creating a parameterized query with exactly enough value placeholders (question marks) as the input array has items, and then runs the `DELETE` as a single operation.